# How to sample a dataset to make sure it's valid?

Tags: sampling

Perhaps this may be a repeated question, but I have very little knowledge in this field (statistics).

I have the following problem:

1. I have two datasets that are composed of addresses.
2. We merge these two datasets, into one, according to our own crazy algorithms;
3. We have this final dataset, divided in three categories (CREATED, MATCHED and REMOVED)
4. In this step, after all the work has been done by a machine, an user, will check the results of a final sample. That means: he will report false matches and match CREATED/REMOVED pairs that the algorithms did not catch on.

Some information about the datasets:

1. These datasets have around ~20k elements each. So the final dataset is a bit larger. It is unpratical to a user sample them all. If we were going to do that, there was no need to merge them using an algorithm;
2. The datasets contains the following information: id, name and address. We are matching them using the address variable.
3. We need to validate the algorithm, that is, are we getting false positive matches? Are we creating or removing stuff that we should have matched?
4. The algorithm has a few variables that can be tweaked by an user. We want to tweak them and compare between each run. While we want to maximize the matches, we don't want to match invalid data.

We are all ok with the above. The hard part for us is how to sample this final dataset.

**edit: we want the system, based on the size of the population, randomly selects records for an user to analyze.

let's say our population is 1000 records, between matched, created and removed.

the system should generate a random sample for 10% of this population, than an user will manually tag as valid or invalid, so we have at least 95% (again, this can vary) of confidence that we are not generating false positives.
**

What is the necessary math to sample it properly, to give us enough confidence in the final product?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the datasets in question and the purpose for sampling?  Is there a reason for you not to use the full, matched dataset?  Why do you feel the need to take a sample from the final dataset?  There are many ways to take a probability sample from a known universe, by the way, ranging from something as simple as simple random sampling or systematic sampling to complex multi-stage cluster sampling.  Really depends on what you're trying to do and what your limited by as far as resources are concerned

Comment: Hello @MarquisdeCarabas! Thanks for the fast answer. I'll update the question.